# Strava authentication Api Login Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, strava

I have implemented Strava authentication in my asp application. I am facing issue with call back url. If I am not login into strava account from browser and then try to connect user with strava from my application, Login prompt appears for strava account. After successfully login Starva dashboard screen opens up. It neither ask for authorization not goes back to my application.

However flow is working fine if i already have login to strava in my browser. Callack url is working perfect for this scenario. 
Here is my call back URL :
https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=+ clientid + "&response_type=code&redirect_uri=www.zbc.com/Starva/CallBack.aspx?Source=1&scope=write";

Comment: Same me on iOS with Swift language.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? I just tested and it works fine for me. After logged out of my Strava account, in the browser I go for `https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&scope=public` , it redirects to Strava login page, I enter my email and password and get redirect to my callback url.